# Wordpress CF7 Countdown field with textarea not changing as user types

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to use the count (down) function by WPCF7 on this page: https://www.inkopia.com/photographer-submissions/ however nothing happens when the user starts to type? I've read the WPCF7 documentation and have followed the instructions to the letter. However nothing happens. I've checked the console log but nothing there is showing there's an issue. Are there any known plugin conflicts with this? It's such a nightmare!

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Countdown function works like this.  Place below in your form.

```
[textarea* Message maxlength:500 placeholder "*Message"]
[count Message down]
```

Make sure that your theme doesn't have anywhere

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_load_js', '__return_false' );
```

See [documentation](https://contactform7.com/loading-javascript-and-stylesheet-only-when-it-is-necessary/) for removal of JS from CF7.  Ensure that there are no instances of the removal of the JS, otherwise this won't work.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. So recently we changed some settings and deferred some JS scripts (the hosting people did this so I don't have much more info). I was using wpcf7.cached = 0; however I removed this and it still wasn't working. I was also using a PHP script in functions.php to defer JS but removed it and still it wasn't working. I know the logic behind the JS to show the countdown so I could just write the JS myself however it's completely against the logic of the function! So I am still a little bit stuck..

Comment: The count function is built in to Contact Form 7, as is the `count down` so if it's not working, then JS is the reason.  Keep digging.  Disable cache, search your theme for `wpcf7_load_js` etc.

Answer (score -1):

You need to get each character from the textarea then show on the div ".wpcf7-character-count". Also, if the WPCF7 don't limit the maximum input to 500 you can create another rule for that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("textarea").on('input', function() {
      var maximum_value = $(".wpcf7-character-count").data("maximum-value");
      var current_value = maximum_value - $(this).val().length;
      $(".wpcf7-character-count").text(current_value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="BIO" cols="40" rows="10" maxlength="500" minlength="200" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Biography (min. 200, max. 500 characters)*"></textarea><br>
<span class="wpcf7-character-count down" data-target-name="BIO" data-starting-value="500" data-current-value="500" data-maximum-value="500" data-minimum-value="200">500</span>
```

Comment: Why are you including jQuery 3.3.1?  Also... Why would you include it this way?

Comment: @HowardE you have add the jQuery tag. So, I've add 3.3.1 just for testing but you can use latest version.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. However this goes against the logic of the CF7 functionality.. it should work without adding additional JS code. I think its because of some deferred scripts I think.